# Undefined Function Error when using pop Lisp

Tags: list, common-lisp

When testing a lisp function I hard-coded in a list. This then generated the follow error when using `pop`:

```
(pop '(1 2 3))
```

> EVAL: 1 is not a function name; try using a symbol instead

However using `car` works fine:

```
(car'(1 2 3))
> 1
```

I assume this is because `pop` expects a variable into which it can re-store the remainder of the list.

If so, where does the current error message come from and why is it so incredibly unhelpful? It doesn't even mention `pop` as being the problem.

Comment: See `(macroexpand '(pop '(1 2 3)))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The predefined macro [`pop`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_pop.htm) takes as parameter **not a list value** but a [place](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_p.htm#place), that is a form which evaluates to a location (for a general description, see the [Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_aa.htm)). For instance:

```
CL-USER> (let ((stack '(1 2 3)))
           (print (pop stack))
           (print stack)
           "Done!")    

1 
(2 3) 
"Done!"
```

For the reason of the error message: `car` takes as parameter a list, so that `'(1 2 3)` is a quoted form which, when **evaluated**, produces the list `(1 2 3)`; finally the first element of this list, `1`, is returned by `car`. In the case of `pop`, which is a macro, not a function, the form `(pop '(1 2 3))` has an expansion which is something like:

```
(LET* ((#:G10655 (1 2 3)) ...)
```

from which you can see that the list `(1 2 3)` is evaluated, and this produces the error message:

> EVAL: 1 is not a function name; try using a symbol instead

In fact, in this evaluation, `(1 2 3)` is taken as a form, and the system tries to apply the function `1` to the arguments `2 3`, and this is an error since `1` is not a function.

Unhelpful messages are typical of languages with macros, when the error happens *after* the macro-expansion phase: for this reason it is very useful the use of tools, like `macroexpand`, that allow to see the result of this phase, as in `(macroexpand '(pop '(1 2 3)))` as suggested by @jkiiski in the comment.

Comment: Unhelpful messages are typical of lack of validations and/or lack of effort writing the error message (maybe due to personal time constraints, to keep code fast, etc.)  It doesn't have much to do with the language.  For instance, [SICL](https://github.com/robert-strandh/SICL) has a lot more validations along with helpful messages.

Comment: @acelent, I tried `(pop '(1 2 3))`in SBCL and got a message that I doubt would be particularly useful: `; in: POP '(1 2 3)
;     (1 2 3)
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   illegal function call
; in: POP '(1 2 3)
;     (FUNCALL #'(SETF QUOTE) #:NEW456 #:G457)
; ==>
;   (SB-C::%FUNCALL #'(SETF QUOTE) #:NEW456 #:G457)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   The function (SETF QUOTE) is undefined, and its name is reserved by ANSI CL so
;   that even if it were defined later, the code doing so would not be portable.
; 
; compilation unit finished... Undefined function:
;     (SETF QUOTE)`...